# Why does the moon becomes red instead blue during an lunar eclipse?

Tags: optics, gravity, eclipse

While observing an lunar eclipse, I noticed that the moon is first covered by a distinct strip of blue light, to then at its apogee, the moon is completed covered by a red light. I understand that the redness appearance of the moon is caused by the scattering of light caused by Earth atmosphere. In other words, it is the sunset and sunrise around the world projected on the moon. But If the blue light scatters 5 times more than red, which means, it curves more dramatically than the red light, what is precluding the blue light from taking over the red?

Comment: The man source of light on the moon during totality is not the light that is scattered by Earth's atmosphere, it's the light that is _transmitted through_ the atmosphere.  I.e., it is the light that is _not_ scattered.  It's exactly what you said:  If you could stand on the moon at that moment and look toward Earth, you'd see a "sunset" encircling the entire globe.  It's red for the same reason that a sunset is red when you observe it while standing on a West-facing beach on Earth.

Comment: @James large you also would see a large blue filter, several times larger than the red portion of the atmosphere. If you shine a light in a prism, the blue light change its course by a much steeper angle than the red, yet during the eclipse, the red seems to be following a steeper curve or at least a similar curve of the blue light. Why?

Comment: [Scattering of blue light by Earth's atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) is not the same phenomenon as [dispersion of light by a prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(optics)).  The blue light of the sky is extremely diffuse.  A single ray of blue light entering a prism would exit as a single ray, but a single ray of blue light passing through the atmosphere is scattered over a broad range of directions.

Comment: Also, If you're standing on the Moon during a total lunar eclipse, then you're looking at the _night_ side of the Earth.  The night sky isn't blue.  The blue sky is all on the daylight side---facing away from you.